# Understanding an exercise about gradients and vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

In John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, exercise 11.17 goes as follows:

> Let $f(x,y)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$, and let $X$ be the vector field $$X=\operatorname{grad} f=2x\frac\partial{\partial x}.$$ Compute the coordinate expression for $X$ in polar coordinates (on some open subset on which they are defined) and show that it is *not* equal to $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}.\tag{*}$$

---

I am not sure, what I am supposed to do here, but this is what I thought: Considering the change of coordinates $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ we can compute the change of bases of tangent spaces:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
&=\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
&=-r\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+r\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\end{align}
$$
and then since $f(r,\theta)=r^2\cos^2\theta$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}&=2r\cos^2\theta\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}&=-2r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta
\end{align}
$$
we see that the coefficient of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in $(*)$ becomes
$$
2r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-2r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\neq 0
$$
but to equal $X$, this coefficient should have been identical zero. I chose to use $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ instead of $(r,\theta)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\tan^{-1}(y/x))$ which is limited to $x>0$ and more heavy to work with.

But I would like to know, if what I write here even makes sense, or if I am way off.

Comment: What you're done is correct, but the exercise also asks you compute $X$ is polar coordinates. You don't need to use the chain rule again, you just have to invert the matrix in your system, ra

Comment: @ArturAraujo: Thank you! I will do that and return to it later.

Comment: @Michael: Hi Michael! Yes, that was me :) Great to hear from you. I left that site when they gave it "an extreme makeover" so that noone could find anything anymore ;) And this site has the MathJaX-advantage ...

Answer (score 2):

One mistake in your computation:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=-2r^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$

The others look correct to me. However in the problem, I understand $X=\nabla f$. But then what does $2x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ mean?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I missed the the derivative of the inner function there! The tangent space consists of derivations in this abstract setup. So here $2x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a derivation that for a given smooth function $g$ defined on our manifold $\mathbb R^2$ can assign a number in $\mathbb R$. Furthermore, a derivation $v:C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^2)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ must satisfy the Leibniz (product) rule $v(gh)=v(g)h+g v(h)$, which in particular the differential operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ does. At least that is how I have understood it this far.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Why is $X$ a vector field then, if $2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a derivation that assigns $g$ a number in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because $2x{\partial_x}\bigg|_{(x,y)}$ then is a tangent vector at $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The coordinate function $2x$ (which maps $(x,y)\mapsto 2x$) is smooth, therefore $X$ is a section in the tangent bundle, i.e. by definition a vector field.